# How to properly type nested classes with generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics, inner-classes

I'm trying to get the C# equivalent of this Kotlin code:

```kotlin
class Baz<E>(val value: E)

class Foo<T>(val toto: Baz<T>) {

    class Bar<U>(toto: Baz<U>) : Foo<U>(toto) {

        val tata: U = toto.value

    }

}
```

This works because the `U` in `Bar` is the same as the `T` in `Foo`, so the same as `E` in `Baz`.

Keep in mind that `Bar` is a nested class, not an inner class, so `Bar` couldn't have a type for `toto` if it didn't have the generic `U`.

I then tried to replicate it in C# like this:

```cs
public class Baz<E> {
    public E Value;

    public Baz(E value) {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class Foo<T> {
    public T Toto;

    public Foo(T toto) {
        Toto = toto;
    }

    public class Bar<U> : Foo<U> {
        public U Tata;

        public Bar(U toto) : base(toto) {
            Tata = toto.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

However, with this implementation, I get the error `Cannot convert source type 'U' to target type 'T'`.

Why doesn't it work and how can I fix it?

Comment: In C#, the compiler/Roslyn will strongly warn you against using nested types in any generic type because it's a PITA to correctly fully-qualify type-names - and it results in counterintuitive handling of `static` fields, for example.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance of the JVM world (...for good reason!) - but what is the difference between a "nested class" and an "inner class"?

Comment: Your Kotlin code has `Foo` accept a `Baz<T>`  - but your C# code has `Foo` accept a `T` - not a `Baz<T>` - is that intentional?

Comment: @Dai In JVM/Kotlin (since Kotlin also has JS and Native support), an inner can access the members of its outer class and carry a reference to an object of an outer class, while a nested class does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, with this implementation, I get the error Cannot convert source type 'U' to target type 'T'.

Just remove `U`, because `Bar<U>` is already generic over `T` in `Foo<T>`:

This compiles for me:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public readonly T Toto;

    public Foo( T toto )
    {
        this.Toto = toto;
    }

    public class Bar : Foo<T>
    {
        public readonly T Tata;

        public Bar( T toto )
            : base( toto )
        {
            this.Tata = toto;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to allow `Bar` to have its own type-parameter that's bound to `T` that's also doable (but of questionable utility, imo):

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public readonly T Toto;

    public Foo( T toto )
    {
        this.Toto = toto;
    }

    public class Bar<U> : Foo<T>
        where U : T
    {
        public readonly U Tata;

        public Bar( U toto )
            : base( toto )
        {
            this.Tata = toto;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in order to use `Bar<U>` you need to qualify it as `Foo<T>.Bar<U>`:

```
Foo<T> foo = new Foo<T>.Bar<U>( ... );
```

...so when `T == U` you end-up with this:

```
Foo<String> foo = new Foo<String>.Bar<String>( "lolwut" );
```